# Disable checkbox cell in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# form in which I have a dataGridView. In dataGridView, I have some columns with string text which is coming from database. I have two other columns which have checkboxes. I want to make these row read-only according to certain condition. I have tried to make the entire row readonly which only affected the text columns and not the checkbox columns.
I want to disable checkbox columns such that they cant be edited (they should remain in fixed state).

So far I have tried this. I have a list(disabledRow) which contains values of rows that need to be disabled

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // Check if the cell value in the first column matches any value in the list
    if (disabledRows.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString()))
    {
        // Set the entire row to ReadOnly
        row.ReadOnly = true;
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you create your dgw programatically? If I create my sample demo according to your needs programatically, I get the behaviour you're looking for.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class SampleData
    {
        public string StringData { get; set; }
        public bool Checkbox1Data { get; set; }
        public bool Checkbox2Data { get; set; }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        // Create a string column
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn stringColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "String Column",
            DataPropertyName = "StringData",
        };
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(stringColumn);

        // Create a checkbox column 1
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Checkbox 1",
            DataPropertyName = "Checkbox1Data",
        };
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn1);

        // Create a checkbox column 2
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn2 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Checkbox 2",
            DataPropertyName = "Checkbox2Data",
        };
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn2);

        // Create a data source with sample data
        var dataSource = new BindingList<SampleData>
        {
            new SampleData { StringData = "Row 1", Checkbox1Data = false, Checkbox2Data = true },
            new SampleData { StringData = "Row 2", Checkbox1Data = true, Checkbox2Data = false },
            new SampleData { StringData = "Row 3", Checkbox1Data = false, Checkbox2Data = false }
        };

        dataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;

        // Add the DataGridView to the form
        Controls.Add(dataGridView);

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("Row 1");
        strings.Add("Row 2");


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows) 
        {
            if (strings.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(row.ReadOnly.ToString());
                row.ReadOnly = true;
                MessageBox.Show(row.ReadOnly.ToString());
            }
        }
        dataGridView.Refresh();
}
}
```